# Exc_bad_access using sqlite3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

The app crash (NOT ALL THE TIME) with the message "Exc_bad_access"

```
// 1. Get the path for phone DB
const char * dbpath = [self.DBPath UTF8String];

// 2. Open database
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // 3. Create request
    NSString * statementGetBillingAccount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT billing_account FROM account;"];
    const char * sql_stmt_getBillingAccount  = [statementGetBillingAccount UTF8String];

    // 4. Execute request
    sqlite3_stmt * sqlStatement;

    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getBillingAccount, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
```

and stop to the line

```
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getBillingAccount, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
```

In xCode/console sqlite3_stmt * sqlStatement is NULL:

```
self    AccueilViewController * class name = AccueilViewController  0x1696c800
sqlResult   int 665035512   665035512
sql_stmt_getBillingAccount  const char *    "SELECT billing_account FROM account;"  0x15e7cac9
sqlStatement    sqlite3_stmt *  NULL    0x00000000
statementGetBillingAccount  NSString *  @"SELECT billing_account FROM account;" 0x15e7cac0
_contactDB  sqlite3 *   0x15e7cb00  0x15e7cb00
```

Can someone explain me what's happend ? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you paste the crash log of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: exc_bad_access(code=1, address=0x29)

Comment: No stack trace? really?